# Can I stop the bot replying to Line temporarily or not?

Tags: dialogflow-es

To answer Line OA uses Dialogflow to help answer.
Then there will be a shutdown for the company's system maintenance. If the customer, no matter what messages are sent, wants the bot to reply that there is a system maintenance shutdown, can he or she want to close all other intents or pause first? if a user sends a message to Response, they only have to reply in one sentence. Can I do it? How?

I'm curious if there is a way to make it possible. How to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.